# LocalReports in C# causing Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException

Tags: c#, mysql, reporting-services, xsd, localreport

Does anybody know how I can get around this error or what it means?

Error: Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException

Inner exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException

(I put the full error as a comment inside the catch block in code snippet below)

This is my first attempt to run local reports / report viewer inside VS 2010, but this render method is exploding every time, and google seems not to turn up much help.

Can you spot any obvious mistakes?

FYI stuff not shown is a very simple XSD with one datatable, which is populated in the code to be used as a dataset, and one rdlc file (the report), which has one table in it and uses a datasource with just the one dataset (the xsd).

Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    private const string UID = "myLogin";
    private const string PASSWORD = "myPassword";
    private const string IP = "myServerIPaddress";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = GetMySqlConnetion("schools"))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT `venrollmentandmaxenrollment`.`classId`,
                                        `venrollmentandmaxenrollment`.`NumberOfStudentsEnrolled`,
                                        `venrollmentandmaxenrollment`.`NumberOfMaxEnrollments`
                                    FROM `schools`.`venrollmentandmaxenrollment`;";

                    MySqlDataReader sessionReportReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
                    dataSet1.Load(sessionReportReader, System.Data.LoadOption.Upsert, dataSet1.Tables[0].TableName);
                    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
                    viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\VS\\TestReports\\TestReports\\Report1.rdlc";
                    viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSet1.Tables[0].TableName, dataSet1.Tables[0]));
                    byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
                    //TODO: do something with bytes, and drag this code back to the main application, once we get this working!
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /*
             LocalReport.Render always takes us here with this exception:
             * 
             Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException occurred
              Message=An error occurred during local report processing.
              Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
              StackTrace:
                   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
              InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException
                   Message=An error has occurred during report processing.
                   Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
                   ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsProcessingAborted&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=1.0
                   SkipTopLevelMessage=false
                   StackTrace:
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.AbortHelper.ThrowAbortException(String reportUniqueName)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.CheckAndThrowIfAborted()
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.FetchData(Boolean mergeTran)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.PrefetchData(ReportInstance reportInstance, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, Boolean mergeTran)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.FetchData(ReportInstance reportInstance, Boolean mergeTransaction)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ProcessOdpReport(Report report, OnDemandMetadata odpMetadataFromSnapshot, ProcessingContext pc, Boolean snapshotProcessing, Boolean reprocessSnapshot, Boolean processUserSortFilterEvent, Boolean processWithCachedData, ErrorContext errorContext, DateTime executionTime, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, StoreServerParameters storeServerParameters, GlobalIDOwnerCollection globalIDOwnerCollection, SortFilterEventInfoMap oldUserSortInformation, EventInformation newUserSortInformation, String oldUserSortEventSourceUniqueName, ExecutionLogContext executionLogContext, OnDemandProcessingContext& odpContext)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition, Boolean& dataCached)
                        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition)
                        at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CreateSnapshotAndRender(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, ReportProcessing repProc, IRenderingExtension renderer, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, SubreportCallbackHandler subreportHandler, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials)
                        at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, ParameterInfoCollection reportParameters, IEnumerable dataSources, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
                        at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
                   InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException
                        Message=DataSet1
                        Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
                        ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsErrorCreatingDataReader&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=1.0
                        SkipTopLevelMessage=false
                        StackTrace:
                             at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.RunDataSetQuery()
                             at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeOnDemandDataSet.Process()
                             at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.ProcessConcurrent(Object threadSet)
                        InnerException: 

             */
        }
    }

    public static MySqlConnection GetMySqlConnetion(string DB)
    {
        string connStr = String.Format(
            "SERVER={0}; Port={1}; UID={2}; PASSWORD={3}; DATABASE={4}; pooling={5};",
            IP,
            "3306",
            UID,
            PASSWORD,
            DB,
            "false");

        MySqlConnection mycon = null;
        try
        {
            mycon = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            mycon.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Logger logger = new Logger("Test Reports App");
            logger.Log(ex);
        }

        return mycon;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can bind a `DataSet` directly to a `ReportDataSource`. You need to wrap it in something like a `BindingSource`

Comment: The ReportDataSource takes a datatable or an IEnumerable type. I haven't tried binding. Is it necessary to use binding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class to bind your data to.

```
public class MyReportClass
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then populate the class using a `DataReader`

```
//snippet
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// add to collection
List<MyReportClass> myReportClassCollection = new List<MyReportClass.();

while (reader.Read())
{
  // populate entity
  var myReportClass = new MyReportClass();
  // set properties, skipping DBNull checking for quickness
  myReportClass.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
  myReportClass.Name = (string) reader["Name"];

  myReportClassCollection.Add(myReportClass);
}

 ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
 viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
 viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\VS\\TestReports\\TestReports\\Report1.rdlc";
 viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("myDataSource", myReportClassCollection));
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, but im getting the same error with your code. Perhaps the issue is not with the data source at all, but with the report. But.. the report is bare-bones, I am really stumped here.

Comment: Delete and recreated your dataset in your RDLC file to map to the newly generated class. Also check your expressions in your RDLC. You might want to open the report natively with the Report Viewer first to ensure it renders correctly.

Comment: GOT IT!! Renaming "myDataSource" to "DataSet2" solved my issue. Apparently, this name must be exactly the same as the dataset name inside of the rdlc file. That combined with the code in your answer, and the exception stops.. Thanks for your help today, have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a LocalProcessingException from the Render statement because I was rendering to a filestream for a file in a directory (specifically, the Program Files (x86) folder -- OOPS) for which the user did not have write permissions. It was not able to create the file when it tried to Render and so it threw the LocalProcessingException.

So check the location of the file/filestream you're trying to render to, and check the user's permissions as well. Note I did not have this issue on my development machine where I have full permissions for pretty much everything.

Hope this helps someone out there, even if it was a pretty dumb problem of my own making.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSet1.Tables[0].TableName, dataSet1.Tables[0]));
```

by this one

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSet1.DataSetName, dataSet1.Tables[0]));
```